# How do I insert an iframe inside SwiftUI View?

Tags: webview, uiwebview, webkit, swiftui

I want to load a `webView` inside the new SwiftUI framework. How can I do that?

```
struct SubmissionFlowFrame: View {

    var body: some View {
        // I want to insert the iframe here
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless it's a native SwiftUI `View` (which I don't believe it is), you'll need to (1) get it working in `UIKit` as you want (either as a view or view controller) and (2) make it "relatable" (as in `UIViewRelatable` or `UIViewControllerRelatable`. There are a few questions here with accepted answers along with a few pretty good examples out there. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You can use any `UIView` by conforming to `UIViewRepresentable` and implement needed methods like this:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {

        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)

        view.load(request)
    }
}
```

and then use it like a normal swiftUI `View` like this:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {
        WebView()
    }
}
```

And don't forget to import `UIKit` dependencies like for this case:

```
import WebKit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) -> WebView.UIViewType {
        WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://apple.com")!)
        uiView.load(request)
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        WebView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, currently no direct methods are available for that.

but you can use `UIViewRepresentable` for that and wrap view with it.

like this:

```
struct ContentView : UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) { }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

don't forget to `import WebKit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `webView` inside SwiftUI using `UIViewRepresentable`.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    WebView()
  }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    return WKWebView()
  }
  func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
        webView.load(request)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebView` to load url request like:

```
WebView {
    $0.load(URLRequest(url: .init(string: "https://google.com")!))
}
```

---

With this simple struct

```
import WebKit
struct WebView: ViewRepresentableHelper {
    var configuration = { (view: WKWebView) in } //  This has a gift for you
}
```

---

## Bouns!

You can replace `WKWebView` with almost **ANY** other `UIKit` or `AppKit` component to make it available right in the SwiftUI code!
For example:

```
struct IndicatorView: ViewRepresentableHelper {
    var configuration = { (view: UIActivityIndicatorView) in }
}
```

usage:

```
IndicatorView {
    $0.startAnimating()
}
```

---

#### Works on both iOS and macOS

Dont forget to implement this powerful extesnion:

```
#if os(macOS)
public typealias ViewRepresentable = NSViewRepresentable
public typealias NativeView = NSView
#elseif os(iOS)
public typealias ViewRepresentable = UIViewRepresentable
public typealias NativeView = UIView
#endif

public protocol ViewRepresentableHelper: ViewRepresentable {
    associatedtype ViewType: NativeView
    var configuration: (ViewType) -> () { get set }
    func new() -> ViewType
}

public extension ViewRepresentableHelper {
    func new() -> ViewType { ViewType() }
}

public extension ViewRepresentableHelper {
    func makeView(_ context: Context) -> ViewType {
        let view = new()
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        return view
    }
    func updateView(_ view: ViewType, _ context: Context) { configuration(view) }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ViewType { makeView(context) }
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> ViewType { makeView(context) }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ViewType, context: Context) { updateView(uiView, context) }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: ViewType, context: Context) { updateView(nsView, context) }
}
```